# Exporting MXD layout view to GeoTIFF?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, mxd, layouts, geotiff-tiff

It my be old issue, but I can't find right solution.

How to produce GeoTIFF from layout view not from data view?

Any simple solution?

Comment: Are you asking how in the layout to go from a graphic image to a geotiff? I'm not sure I fully understand your question.

Comment: I am asking how to produce GeoTIF from layout view in ArcGIS. It is possible to produce GeoPDF, but GeoTIF is only possible from data frame. I am trying to compile GDAL 1.8 with poppler to do so, however its quite problematic...

Comment: He is trying to Rasterize a Map View from MXD file.. that's all... is right @Tomek?

Comment: I am trying to print final map with legend (layout view) as GeoTiff in Arc. It is possible in Arc export GeoTIF from data frame, but not from layout. However there is an option to print whole map in GeoPDF. So, my question is, how come it is possible to get map as GeoPDF but not GeoTIF. I need GeoTIF. My work aroud is to print the map to GeoPDF and with GDAL >1.8 try to convert GeoPDF to GeoTIF. Doable, but sadly it is not that simple as I  need to compile GDAL with poppler liberaries. With no luck.

Comment: Are a lot of packaged GDAL distributions take a look to OSGeo4Win, see the packages in the installer if i'm not wrong, are gdal1.8 suite.

Comment: yes there are a lot of GDAL distr. but non of them contains poppler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To export ArcGIS .mxd page layout with all the page layout elements (multiple frames, graphics) to GeoTiff, you can do it with GDAL >= 1.9.

1. Export map as GeoPDF from ArcMap
2. Convert GeoPDF to GTiff (or any other format supported by GDAL) using gdal_translate

Version GDAL 1.9 comes with poppler lib included (compiled [GDAL download for Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20140730124559/http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1400-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip)), so no additional lib's are required.

Comment: I noticed this useful discussion of the relevant gdal_translate parameters:<br>
http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-GeoPDF-translation-td3742508.html<br>

Answer (score 3):

Export to GeoTiff from layout view is available as part of the production mapping environment.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0106000002tt000000.htm

Comment: It requires Nautical Solution and I do not have it. Otherwise it seems as a good solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That would make some sense.
Because the layout only has page coordinates (eg 8.5x11).

I used to do a similar function in autocad where I replicated the page dimensions (scaled of course) and porportion in the model space (data frame) and printed to file from there.

It might be some work if you have symbollogy and scale you are trying to replicate from the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Is a pity, but the only way to open a MXD file to automaticly convert to another is using ArcGIS Scripting =(. Because since GDAL is open source, and ArcGIS does not have provided a library free to use to read mxd files, is impossible at this way if you are not using and ESRI product.

You could open in ArcMap, or ArcCatalog and go in ArcToolBox in Conversion tools could be an option like Feature to Raster (now i'm not have ArcGIS in my job workstation).

Maybe you could export to another format, like MapInfo, or Autodesk DXF using the Data Inoperability (Data Interoperability) Module.

hope this be useful... have a nice day.

EDIT: a bit of light in the python scripting stuff http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/26858-Feature-to-raster-Python-very-slow-in-ArcGIS-10

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS Desktop they have not exposed all of the functionality that is available.

I would suggest writing a Python Script using the ExporttoTiff tool.

Here is a [reference document](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000009000000), notice the "create world file" Boolean flag.

Comment: In this way you can not export legend. So, basically you receive same thing as printing GeoTIFF from data view.