# Exporting GeoTIffs from Data Driven Pages for use on Tablet?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geotiff-tiff, data-driven-pages, tablet

I'm a beginner at ArcGIS 10.2 and have encountered a small problem that I couldn't solve by googling. I'm trying to export a set of raster and vector data for use on a tablet. The aim is to find LiDAR features in the field using the GPS from the tablet and I want to be able to switch between various visualizations and the polygons and lines of the interpretation.

For this purpose I try to batch create GeoTiffs with various visualizations of the data and export them using Data Driven Pages, since it lets you very conveniently tile a map and I wanted to create a hard copy mapbook of the data anyway. I found an ArcPy script that batch exports Data Driven Pages to tiffs and this is working fine, with the major problem that it's not possible to include spatial information when exporting from a Layout. Since I'm generating a very lage amount of tiles (over 600) and would like to do so with various visualizations, manually georeferencing them is not an option.

Answer (score 6):

A work around would be to use the [ExportToTIFF](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000009000000) method within the data driven page loop.  Here is a code example:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
        mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Temp\image_{0}.tif".format(pageNum), df, df_export_width=600, df_export_height=400, geoTIFF_tags=True)
```

Comment: This exports the view to a geotiff and it's very useful, but I always got a slight distortion using it.  On an ESRI Forum a user  suggested adding the following line (ar=df.extent.height/df.extent.width) and then in the export line for height multiply the number by ar (e.g in the above example 400*ar.  This fixed my issues.  Perhaps my problem was machine specific.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot see a Data Driven Pages solution for exporting layouts to GeoTIFF becoming available until that is possible to do in the core product without DDP being involved.

Ideas for workarounds to that can be found at:

[Exporting MXD layout view to GeoTIFF?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14475/how-to-export-mxd-layout-view-to-geotiff)

At the same time I think you will be wise to look for or create an ArcGIS Idea to have this implemented.